# Trouble with injecting Callable

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I'm using `python-dependency-injector`.

I tried this code and it worked perfectly:
https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/callable.html

that page also mentioned next:

> Callable provider handles an injection of the dependencies the same way like a Factory provider.

So I went and wrote this code:

```
import passlib.hash

from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    password_verifier = providers.Callable(passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.verify)


@inject
def bar(password_verifier=Provide[Container.password_verifier]):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = Container()
    container.wire(modules=[__name__])

    bar()
```

And it -- as you might expect -- didn't work. I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/common/learning_2022/code/python/blog_engine/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    bar()
  File "src/dependency_injector/_cwiring.pyx", line 26, in dependency_injector._cwiring._get_sync_patched._patched
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx", line 225, in dependency_injector.providers.Provider.__call__
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx", line 1339, in dependency_injector.providers.Callable._provide
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pxd", line 635, in dependency_injector.providers.__callable_call
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pxd", line 608, in dependency_injector.providers.__call
TypeError: GenericHandler.verify() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'secret' and 'hash'
```

Comment: so it seems like, injected Callable will always be called on injection
the only way around wold be using the container without injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem too and after much search I found the answer.

You can inject the callable by using the provider attribute:

```
import passlib.hash

from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    # Use the 'provider' attribute on the provider in the container
    password_verifier = providers.Callable(passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.verify).provider


@inject
def bar(password_verifier=Provide[Container.password_verifier]):
    password_verifier(...) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = Container()
    container.wire(modules=[__name__])

    bar()
```

Comment: `password_verifier = providers.Object(passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.verify)` might work too

Answer (score 0):

The method `passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.verify` requires two positional arguments, `secret` and `hash` as shown here: https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html

Because you're injecting an attribute of the Container, the DI framework must create an instance of this to inject it into the bar() method. The DI framework is unable to instantiate this object however since the required positional arguments are missing.

If you wanted to use the method in bar(), you'd have to do so without provoking the DI framework to try to create an instance of the object at initialisation time. You could do this with the following:

```
import passlib.hash

from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    password_hasher = providers.Callable(
        passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.hash,
        salt_size=16,
        rounds=10000,
    )
    password_verifier = providers.Callable(passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.verify)


@inject
def bar(container=Provide[Container]):
    hashed_password = container.password_hasher("123")
    assert container.password_verifier("123", hashed_password)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = Container()
    container.wire(modules=[__name__])

    bar()
```

Comment: `the DI framework must create an instance of this to inject it into the bar() method`
ok so I need to inject a "type", need to find out how to do this